# Issue with IE, Joomla and hover

Tags: css, internet-explorer, joomla

I have set up a page in Joomla, and coded a template.

It all works great, but in IE my hovers in CSS doesn't work.

No matter where I do hover on the page, it simply doesn't react in IE.
...Works great on all other browsers though.

If I set up a page, that is not using Joomla, the hover works perfect, so I think it has something to do with Joomla.

I couldn't find anything about this problem on google, so has anyone had this problem and do you know have to solve?

Thanks.

Comment: You're going to have to give us a bit more of a clue than that.... maybe show us some actual code?

Comment: As simple as this:

#example {
background-image: url(mypath/image.jpg);
}

#example:hover {
background-image: url(mypath/image-hover.jpg);
}

...Wont work.

Comment: I use IE version 10..

Comment: Do you have a URL of the site? As it could be one of a 1000 things.
[link](http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/783569/hover-on-div-not-working) IE 10 Error on div:hover

Comment: I've created an exact replica of your code you just provided but using different images. http://jsfiddle.net/yKg6R/ I've tested this in IE10 and it works fine. Please provide a link to your site